# What start up services can i remove from this long list

Tags: systemd

I read that Linux comes with the default setup that doesn't necessarily pertain to each individual user, before i did a reinstall the time it took from the login to the home screen was less than 3 seconds, now with a new install its near one minute, is there a quintessential program I need to boot up or can I delete them all

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these services should be affecting how long it takes you to log in.  They start when the system boots, not when you log in.  A few of them, it might be harmless to disable.  You might disable `man-db.service` (but then you'll have to remember to occasionally rebuild the man db if anything as changed.  You could probably disable `apparmor.service` if you're not using AppArmor for anything.  You could disable `apt-daily-upgrade.service` (but then your system would not do automatic daily updates).  If you disable any of the rest of them, your system should still "boot", per se - but it may no longer be able to perform functions that you expect it to perform, or it may no longer be able to tell you if it's having various kinds of problems.  If you go looking for the unit definitions for these services in `/usr/lib/systemd`, most of them probably have a comment in them that explains what they do.  You'll probably see that you don't want to disable them.

I'm not sure why your login time would increase from "less than 3 seconds" to "almost a minute" if you did a clean reinstall of the exact same version of the exact same Linux distro on the exact same hardware.  It sounds to me like a more likely culprit is services being started by your desktop environment to support the use of the graphical desktop environment (and none of these services are that).  But wherever the delay is, it's almost certainly not in this list of systemd units.